# ES6 Promise with the "co" module

Tags: node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I was trying to use the ES6 `Promise` with the "co" module to write the async code without callback. Though actual async call is neat and clean, I still have to add wrapper method to return `Promise` object which made it little bulky. Any feedback to improve this code quality will be appreciated.

```
crud.js
'use strict';
const db = require("./dbmanager").db;
const co = require("co");

module.exports = {

  getAllDocuments: (collectionName)=> {

    //This line of code returning "Promise" object make code bulky. Now I have two wrapper, one for "Promise" and second for "co".
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      co(function*() {
        let docs = yield db.collection(collectionName).find().toArray();
        resolve(docs);

      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

    });
  }

}; 

book.js

'use strict';
const dbcrud   = require("./../mongodb/crud");
const co = require("co");
module.exports = {

  getTransactions: (callback) => {
    co(function*() {

      var books = yield dbcrud.getAllDocuments('books');
      callback(null, books);

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(err));
      callback(err, null);
    });
  }

};
```

Comment: Does this work? It doesn't look like it should... `.find()` normally doesn't return something you can call `.toArray()` on.

Comment: yes, it works. I am doing the poc code and for now its working.

Comment: Doesn't `co` return a promise?

Comment: Don't know. Document of "co" doesn't show it does. Need to explore more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through the `"co"` GitHub code, I was able to remove the extra boilerplate code. I made following changes to improve my code:

1. Used the `"co"` promise and return it in my async function. This help to remove the extra "Promise" wrapper code.
2. To resolve the "co" promise, I returned the "Promise" as per fails/success scenario.
3. When making call to MongoDB native driver, used `".catch"` to catch the error there itself and apply logic.

Following is my final version which is neater and cleaner using the `"co"` module:

## crud.js

```
'use strict';
const db = require("./dbmanager").db;
const co = require("co");

module.exports = {

  getAllDocuments: (collectionName)=> {
      //return the "co" promise instead of using "Promise" boilerplate code
      co(function*() {
        let docs = yield db.collection(collectionName).find().toArray().catch(function(err) {
        //in case of error, return the custom message and log the error returned by mongodb driver
        console.log('Error occurred to get documents', err);
        return Promise.reject(new Error(`Error occurred to get documents`)); //return the Promise which will be used by "co"
      });
        return Promise.resolve(docs); //return the Promise which will be used by "co"

      });  
  }
};
```

### book.js

```
'use strict';
const dbcrud   = require("./crud");
const co = require("co");
module.exports = {

  getTransactions: (req, res) => {
   //use "co" to make asyn function call without callback
    co(function*() {
      let transactions = yield dbcrud.getTransactions('transactions');
      res.json(transactions);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(`[ERROR:Controller:API:getTransactions]: error`, err);
      res.status(500);
      res.json({error: err.message});
    });
  },

};
```